# Give margin to one specific cell, UICollectionVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I got a problem and I cant find an answer on stackoverflow and in google to this one, I got a `UICollectionVIew` with this format:

```
 _______
|xxxxxxx|
| xxxxx |
| xxxxx |
| xxxxx |
| xxxxx |
|_______|
```

and I want to give a margin in the first cell to get something like this:

```
 _______
|xxxxxxx|
|       |
| xxxxx |
| xxxxx |
| xxxxx |
|_______|
```

I have tried to give margin to the cell but that gives the margin to every single cell and its not what I want, just for that single cell with `indexPath.item == 0.`

is that possible? if not what can I do to achieve that layout? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`? If so I'd recommend making use of a header view for your first cell:

```
 _______
|xxxxxxx|
```

and reserve `UICollectionViewCell` for the remaining items:

```
| xxxxx |
| xxxxx |
| xxxxx |
|_______|
```

`UICollectionView` supports three different types of items;

- Cells
- Supplementary Views
- Decoration Views

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` provides two ready-to-use Supplementary Views, a header view and a footer view. The header view sounds perfect for your needs here.

Once you've implemented the header views, the margin you describe can be achieved by adjusting the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` `sectionInset` property. Or implementing the delegate method:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
```

There's a bunch of material on the web describing Header/Footer views;

http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/

I also recommend the [Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) - it's a long but excellent read. Especially if you ever need to configure any custom layouts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So how could I start the indexpath.item at 1 instead of 0 in the collectionVIew? since the header will be the first indexpath

if (indexPath.item == 0){ return cell} ?

Comment: Cell, Supplementary Views and Decoration Views all maintain their own index paths, so adding a header view doesn't bump the index path of the first cell to (0,1), the first header view and first cell will both share the index path (0,0). So when you implement `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` you just return the cell types, indexed from 0,0. For the header view you would implement `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` and return the header. This is also indexed from 0,0. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, I understand what i should do now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make two collection view cell type. One wider with some free space at bottom. And second for others.

Comment: thats an easy way to do it and I managed to do it with your answer, but i think the other answer is the most correct. I can be wrong, if I am tell me please, just want the best way to do it right